# Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements GreenDroid

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, greendroid

When I try to make a make an Android app with GreenDroid, so I put the code in there but it asks for a `;` while there already is one.

as people asked for the whole code hereby the whole code!

```
import greendroid.app.GDApplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class GreenDroidTest extends GDApplication {

@Override
public Class<?> getHomeActivityClass() {
    return GreenDroidTest.class;
}

@Override
public Intent getMainApplicationIntent() {
return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_url)));
    }

 }
```

And I can't find any solutions. I already tried Cleaning and building the workspace.

Comment: can you post the whole class?

Comment: the problem is somewhere else in the code please plz some more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cut some of that nesting up into multiple lines.  That way you can get better visibility as to the location the compiler is complaining about.  For example

```
1 @Override
2 public Intent getMainApplicationIntent() {
3     return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_url)));
4 }
```

might tell you a semicolon is needed at line 3, but

```
1  @Override
2  public Intent getMainApplicationIntent() {
3      return new Intent(
4          Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
5          Uri.parse(
6              getString(
7                  R.string.app_url
8              )
9          )
10     );
11 }
```

might tell you a semicolon is needed at line 8.

After you have identified where the semicolon is needed, you can happily put the line back together, with a semicolon in the "right" spot.

Comment: I am able to copy the code above without compilererrors. I dont think that method is the reason for the message...

Comment: then look to the code outside of the method, perhaps this is overriding an anonymous object (an object that has no sub-type, but directly overrides abstracts), and the outside constructor block lacks a required terminating semicolon.  In any event, keep a close eye on line numbers, and expand if necessary should the line have too many options for semicolon placement.

Comment: @BC_ Is it possible to use getString(); without Extending Activity Class?

Comment: @EdwinBuck Thank you for that sollution,i trieded it and while trying it solved it self so i don't know why it did that but still, Thank you